# What is this? (1972 house)

Tags: electrical, plumbing, gas

This was on the wall of a 1972 house.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might want to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how the site functions. A clearer picture maybe from a different angle might help. Given what looks like vents around the circumference makes me think it might be an inlet or outlet for an air system of some sort. Does there appear to be a vent behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is a really bad photo , I believe it is a 4 wire phone jack. These were very popular back then you could move a phone room to room at a time when each handset cost extra on the bill. To verify this normally small solid copper wires were connected red, green, yellow black insulation. On higher end homes there may be a 25 pair trunk instead the 2 pair cable , these larger trunk wires were normally used for intercoms.

Comment: Those were heavy duty plugs and the bells took  16V+-  to ring.  Then they went to those small clip in's.+

Comment: I did not remember the ringer voltage (I thought it was higher) but they were fairly large , the index line on top and if I remember one set of pins was closer together is what I remember.  heck I probably have some males in my shop if the boys didn’t toss them when we moved here.

Comment: I think you're right about the voltage being higher... the 16V was the wall wart for the light on the first princess phone. My mom had one.

Comment: Old phone systems used much more current that modern systems.   Here's a photo of a surface mount jack:  http://www.oldphoneshop.com/products/4-prong-jack-for-4-prong-plug.html

Comment: not much more current really. they were REN 1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringer_equivalence_number

Comment: @davem, yes that is what I am thinking of , there are some female units that were more modular and fit in a single gang box like the op’ photo, but your example is the more common version and exactly what I was thinking of.+  for the current I would not expect there to be much difference but I thought the ringer voltage was ~ 100v that or I got shocked from inductive kickback off the ringer coil. It’s Been to many years and I haven’t had a land line for ~20 years to measure the voltage.

Comment: Plain Old Telephone Service (POTS) carries a direct current (DC) at a nominal voltage of -48V when the receiver is on-hook. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service

Comment: Right, the voice circuit and the ringing voltage are different.  While a single phone may have a REN of 1, the Central Office expecst multiple sets in a house, so supplying ringing for 5 REN would be typical.  Poking around on the net, the ring signal would be upto 110v 20 cycle AC P-P on top of the 48v DC.  If you plug in the 1REN impedence of 7000 ohms you get about 20 ma.  Once the phone is detected to go off-hook, that signal is removed. Anyone that's been touching tip and ring when the phone rings, knows what I mean.

Comment: @DaveM I was not sure of the voltage because I thought it was different but could not remember. I built a hold button for home phones in the 70’s when the phone company showed up my grandma thought it might be the reason and pulled them out so when the guy checked everything was fine. I used two low of a resistance and that made the line look like more handsets or something like more REN ? because back then you paid by the number of handsets. Thanks+ Note I did get whacked a few times with incoming calls.